# I am trying to open an HTML page in the console, I keep getting the res.end output

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to host the html pages on the console, and I keep getting the same output of no HTML page.

I have tried to use

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express(); 
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

const requestHandler = (req, res) => {
    res.end("why???? please do not show this");
};

app.get("/aboutus", function(req, res){
    res.send("aboutus.ejs");    
});
```

I expect when I open console 8080 to see the aboutus page and not the req handler output. The server is working as I get the output with the server that it doesn't output an error.

Comment: What happens when you comment the request handler out? That behaviour makes no sense.

Comment: This code on its own does nothing at all since you don't have app.listen there.
I added that and tried it and all i get when i go to /aboutus page is the string "aboutus.ejs" and that's correct since you are not rendering the ejs file using res.render. You haven't assign the requestHandler function to any route so what you claim is nonsence. Are you sure there isn't another procces still running where you used the requestHandler?

Comment: @scitronboy same thing happens when I comment it out.

Comment: @JasonByronBeedle What are the contents of the `aboutus.ejs` file?

Comment: @molda the code for requestHandler is a (req, res) => {}

Comment: @scitronboy It is a html file with links to bootstrap and css.

Comment: Please provide the output you're getting when you hit the page.